# Calculating audio amp output impedance and other general questions

Tags: audio, solenoid, magnetics

I'm 3rd year EE student and I am now doing a project where I'm basically making a supersensitive metal detector using solenoids. Solenoid has about 9 ohm resistance with inductance about 13 mH. theoretical calculation gives ~14-17 mH) and other calculation I did sort of narrows it down to about 13 mH. I'm using a function generator hooked up to an audio amp input and the solenoid hooked up to speaker output to create an alternating magnetic field.

The audio amp is not too high quality (~$100) and the datasheet is really lacking. All it really says is that there is a maximum 40W power output with 4 ohm speaker load, which led me to believe that the output impedance (Thevenin impedance) is 4 ohm. (No data on input and output impedance)

With 1kHz sine wave from the function generator, my calculation shows that 2 uF capacitor in series with the solenoid should make it a resonant circuit. But measuring the current with a multimeter, the maximum current was achieved with capacitive load close to 6 uH, which baffled me as this would put the inductance value of the solenoid way off the theoretical value. Where could I have gone wrong? Do output impedance of audio amp usually have inductive components? I thought it might have capacitance but not inductance. How would you calculate the output impedance of an audio amp?
My solenoid spec: 6.5 cm long, ~1.45 cm radius with ~1100 turns

P.S.: What would you say the maximum current drive of an average audio amp? Mine doesn't seem to go higher than 1.1 A (I_rms). Near the resonant frequency, the current suddenly changes. Like, it would maintain 1.1 I_rms  at 1kHz, but if I change the frequency even by 10 Hz, it drops to 300mA and when I change the frequency back to 1 kHz, the current value doesn't go back to 1.1 A. Instead, it's a bit higher that 300 mA. Really baffled me.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what audio amp you have and what the schematics of it look like. However, audio amps **do not** have output impedance matched to load impedance, and depending on amplifier type, it **can actually** have an inductor at output for stability.

Comment: Did you mean 6µF instead of 6µH?  If so, please click the edit link below the question.

Answer (score 2):

> All it really says is that there is a maximum 40W power output with 4 ohm speaker load, which led me to believe that the output impedance (Thevenin impedance) is 4 ohm.

For frequencies high enough that the cables become transmission lines, you will get maximum power transfer to the load by avoiding reflections. In this case, a matched impedance environment makes sense.

However, at audio frequencies, this is not necessary. In this case, maximum power transfer and maximum efficiency are both achieved with an amplifier having the minimum possible impedance. If it had a resistive impedance, that would burn power without producing any sound.

So, class AB audio amps usually have quite low output impedance over the audio range, certainly less than 0.1 ohms. For class D amps, the impedance of the output filter should be taken into account, but it won't be much either, it's a LC filter with a few µH coil and a cap.

The L and R of your coil are comparable to a loudspeaker's, so an audio amp is a good cheap choice to drive it.

> With 1kHz sine wave from the function generator, my calculation shows that 2 uF capacitor in series with the solenoid should make it a resonant circuit. But measuring the current with a multimeter, the maximum current was achieved with capacitive load close to 6 uH.

Then something's wrong somewhere. You should do a frequency sweep to find the resonant frequency and that will give you the inductance, provided the cap is accurate. You could also use a multimeter capable of measuring inductance in this range.

> What would you say the maximum current drive of an average audio amp?

That really depends on the amp, so it's not possible to answer without posting a link. I mean, sure, an amp labeled "40W into 4 ohms" should output at least 3.16A RMS, because P=R.I^2 and 4ohms*3.16V^2 is 40W. But, then, there is marketing. If these specs are "musical watts" or "PMPO watts" then who knows. Or perhaps a protection circuit triggers, which could explain the different waveforms you see. So please put a link. Also, your power supply could be unable to provide the current, or other problems.

Note that your resonant circuit could exceed the safe operating area of the output transistors.

Perhaps your coil is triggering its internal protection. If you make a resonant circuit, the current could be higher

Answer (score 1):

The output power of a cheap amp may be written just to make the device look attractive for an unwary buyer. Pout max. 40W to 4 ohm should be interpreted "we promise that 4 ohm load gets 40 watts or less". So, the promise is exactly fulfilled, if you get for ex. 5W, but never more than it. The seller only exploits the same trick as augurs and fortune tellers - they say what they think the listener wants to hear.

If you simulate a circuit which has a resistor, an inductor and a capacitor in series and just your component values, you see that the load becomes reactive if you have the frequency a little off from the resonance. In resonance it should be 9 ohms. Your amp may have no ability to handle the reactive load, some protection may step in to keep the smoke inside the amp.

If we believe the amp could just feed 40W to a 4 ohm resistance, the output voltage would be about 12,7 Vrms. A good audio amp has milliohms of series resistance. From that voltage your 9 ohm resistance coil could in resonance take current 1.4 amps. But the amp seller did never promised the amp outputs that much, he promised it's not exceeded.

About the resonant frequency: You should check that there's no extra metal near the coil. It's a way for  eddy currents and reduces the inductance just like the metal to be detected. Sorry if I sound offensive, but I have seen a metal detector DIY attempt where the coil had got a metal case for protection.